# Array of Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to create an array of an `UserControl` and add it dynamically into a tabitems.

Here is how I proceed :

```
UserControl1[] UC1 = new UserControl1[it1];    
TabItem[] tabItems = new TabItem[it1];    
tabItems[0].Content = UC1[0];     
_MyTabControl.Items.Add(tabItems[0]);
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do ?

Comment: try this tabItems[0]={Content:UC1[0]};  then _MyTabControl.Items.Add(tabItems[0]);

Comment: Before you really doing this have a read about the MVVM pattern. There are better ways for doing things like this.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this case? What happens?

Comment: @ChandrakantThakkar, your proposal doesn't work...

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I'm sure, but unfortunately i'm not familiar with MVVM as well as WPF. I'm a beginner..

Comment: @mm8 No it doesn't work in this case. The issues is appear on 'tabItems[0].Content = UC1[0]; '     :  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Then you haven't added any elements to the array. See the working example in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add at least one `UserControl` and one `TabItem` to the arrays. This works:

```
int it1 = 1;
UserControl1[] UC1 = new UserControl1[it1];
UC1[0] = new UserControl1();
TabItem[] tabItems = new TabItem[it1];
tabItems[0] = new TabItem();
tabItems[0].Content = UC1[0];
_MyTabControl.Items.Add(tabItems[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mm8